# Ajax file upload, how to send more then one object to the server

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a nice app that uses ajax to post to the server to upload an image, its nice, its easy, its simple and looks like this:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: '/impulse/imageupload',
            type: 'POST',
            data: file,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false
        })...additional success, done, failure functions
```

This file being passed in is saved, and this is all good and well, however i've noticed that there are conflicts, for example if I upload an image named 1.jpg, then someone else uploads an image named 1.jpg then mine will be overwritten, which isn't ideal.

So I was wondering how to pass in more then just the file, for example I want to pass in an additional variable (in this case a unique username so I can prepend this to the image name and use this to make the images unique.

i've tried separating the data using ',' however this just breaks it, help on how to do this would be much appreciated :)

**TL:DR; How do I post more then one object to the server**

Comment: I feel bad just putting a link in an answer so go here this is exactly what you need:  http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: I have looked at this plugin, but its not really what I'm looking for, I simply want to send more then just one thing (in this case an object  and a variable) to the server.

Comment: Well then you'll need to review this subject: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use `FormData` object. This is not supported by all browers.
Try the following link :

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FFormData%2FUsing_FormData_Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)